# Path Display in Label

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, path

Are there any automatic methods for trimming a path string in .NET?

For example:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\nick\My Documents\Tests\demo data\demo data.emx
```

becomes

```
C:\Documents...\demo data.emx
```

It would be particularly cool if this were built into the Label class, and I seem to recall it is--can't find it though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **TextRenderer.DrawText** with **TextFormatFlags.PathEllipsis** flag

```
void label_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Label label = (Label)sender;
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, label.Text, label.Font, label.ClientRectangle, label.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.PathEllipsis);
}
```

> Your code is 95% there. The only
>   problem is that the trimmed text is
>   drawn on top of the text which is
>   already on the label.

Yes thanks, I was aware of that. My intention was only to demonstrate use of `DrawText` method. I didn't know whether you want to manually create event for each label or just  override `OnPaint()` method in inherited label. Thanks for sharing your final solution though.

Answer (score 4):

@ [lubos hasko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467?sort=votes#20495) Your code is 95% there.  The only problem is that the trimmed text is drawn on top of the text which is already on the label.  This is easily solved:

```
    Label label = (Label)sender;
    using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(label.BackColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, label.ClientRectangle);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(
        e.Graphics, 
        label.Text, 
        label.Font, 
        label.ClientRectangle, 
        label.ForeColor, 
        TextFormatFlags.PathEllipsis);
```

Answer (score 3):

Not hard to write yourself though:

```
    public static string TrimPath(string path)
    {
        int someArbitaryNumber = 10;
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        if (directory.Length > someArbitaryNumber)
        {
            return String.Format(@"{0}...\{1}", 
                directory.Substring(0, someArbitaryNumber), fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            return path;
        }
    }
```

I guess you could even add it as an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are thinking on the label is that it will put ... if it is longer than the width (not set to auto size), but that would be

```
c:\Documents and Settings\nick\My Doc...
```

If there is support, it would probably be on the Path class in System.IO

Answer (score 0):

You could use the System.IO.Path.GetFileName method and append that string to a shortened System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName string.

Answer (score 0):

Next code works for folders. I'm using it to display a download path!

```
        public static string TrimPath(string path) {
        string shortenedPath = "";
        string[] pathParts = path.Split('\\');
        for (int i = 0; i < pathParts.Length-1; i++) {
            string part = pathParts[i];
            if (pathParts.Length-2 != i) {
                if (part.Length > 5) { //If folder name length is bigger than 5 chars
                    shortenedPath += "..\\";
                }
                else {
                    shortenedPath += part+"\\";
                }
            }
            else {
                shortenedPath += part+"\\";
            }
           

        }
        return shortenedPath;
    }
```

Example:
Input:
C:\Users\Sandra\Desktop\Proyectos de programación\Prototype\ServerClient\test
output:
C:\Users\..\..\..\..\..\test\